# Scala DRYing try/catch

Tags: scala, logging, try-catch, dry

I find myself repeating simple try/catch blocks that should, IMO, be 1-liners.

For example, let's say I need to convert a uri string date in yyyymmdd format to Joda-Time. With a standard try/catch block the conversion method looks like:

```
def ymd2Date(ymd: Option[String]) = ymd match {
  case Some(date) =>
    try { Right( ymdFormat.parseDateTime(date) ) }
    catch { case e => 
      log.info(e.getMessage)
      Left(None) 
    }
  case None => 
    Left(None) // no uri date param
}
val ymdFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
```

Works well enough, intent is clear, but when I do this kind of try/catch logging for *all* non-critical events, then I seek a way to DRY it out. The search led me to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903481/using-scala-util-control-exception) on scala.util.control.Exception. Helpful, but it's still a bit difficult to grok/make it work in the way I'd like it to. In plain English I just want to say, "catch some-action get-result log-error-type".

So, I hacked this out based on the part of control.Exception I'm interested in (or understand to be useful):

```
class Catcher[T](f: => T) {   
  type Logger = (=> Any) => Unit

  def either[T]( logger: => Logger ) = {
    try { Right(f) }
    catch { case e => 
      logger(e.getMessage)
      Left(None)
    }
  }
}
def catching[T](f: => T) = new Catcher(f)
```

And then use in place of try/catch like so:

```
catching( ymdFormat.parseDateTime(date) ) either log.info
```

Can add on option, a msg prefix, etc., but...it would probably be better to find a way to get control.Exception to work like the above, as the TypeSafe crew is going to produce code worlds better than I'll ever imagine writing.

Does anyone know how to create this kind of syntax using control.Exception where one can pass in a logger function by-name to be used in the catch block?

Would be great if there was a "use cases" for control.Exception, but I get the feeling this utility is for more advanced Scala devs

Comment: Why do you use `Either`? If all you are going to put in `Left` is `None`, then it seems you could use `Option[T]`.

Comment: good point, I wanted to fold over the result and Either seemed like a natural fit...

Comment: which is to say, there is currently no option fold, or at least not built into the language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception
def log(logger: => Logger)(e: Throwable) = {
    logger(e.getMessage)
    None
}
Exception.allCatch withApply log(logger) apply Some(ymdFormat.parseDateTime(date))
```

But this kind of stuff is better handled by Scalaz `Validation`, in my opinion.

Comment: right, have yet to venture down Scalaz row, just getting my feet wet in Scala itself. Validation in its most basic form looks like Either, but then curve ratchets up quickly. It's on the to-do...

Comment: that's pretty cool, btw, looks like I can scrap my hack and take an approach that someone other than myself will understand ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes - For what it's worth, your "hack" is much clearer to me than Daniel's approach (would be clearer still if you didn't call it `catching` but rather `tryOrLog` or something that doesn't suggest that the first argument will itself be caught).

Comment: @Rex, "catching" was just following control.Exception convention. I used to be a pitcher as well, so I guess I like catchers, or at least playing catch ;-) tryOrLog is indeed semantically clearer...

Answer (score 3):

A quick example:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

def throwingStuff {
  throw new Exception("Hello World!")
}

catching(classOf[Exception]).withApply{err => println(err.toString); None}.apply(Some(throwingStuff))
```

You can use `withApply` to override the application logic of the `Catch` class to do something such as writing to a log.

Comment: The return type doesn't quite work with this. `withApply` converts the `Throwable` into a return value, so you'll never get `Left`, and `Right`'s type will be `Any` or `AnyRef`.

Comment: Yep, realised and edited just before your comment! Using `Some` is a good idea, though.

Comment: Need to preserve the type. If I go Option[T] will the type be preserved/accessible?

Comment: Yep - `apply(Some(throwingStuff))` will work as in Daniel's answer.

Comment: hmmm, type needs to be preserved in both cases, Either and Option. In the example I gave, I use Either because I want to fold over the result vs. option match Some/None or getOrElse. At any rate, both need to be accounted for in terms of type preservation. I'll see what type comes back...

Comment: I see what you mean. I've updated the answer to preserve this correctly. You can emulate a `fold` on Option with a combination of `map` and `getOrElse`, of course.