# Scala: Silently catch all exceptions

Tags: scala, exception, functional-programming, try-catch

Empty catch block seems to be invalid in Scala

```
try {
  func()
} catch {

} // error: illegal start of simple expression
```

How I can catch all exceptions without their processing?

Comment: Silently swallowing exceptions is a bad idea - when something goes wrong, you'll never know. At least log the exception.

Comment: @Jesper Sometimes you really don't want to know.  And you don't want your boss to know.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Some exceptions really aren't meant to be caught.  You can request it anyway:

```
try { f(x) }
catch { case _: Throwable => }
```

but that's maybe not so safe.

All the safe exceptions are matched by `scala.util.control.NonFatal`, so you can:

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
try { f(x) }
catch { case NonFatal(t) => }
```

for a slightly less risky but still very useful catch.

Or `scala.util.Try` can do it for you:

```
Try { f(x) }
```

and you can pattern match on the result if you want to know what happened.  (`Try` doesn't work so well when you want a `finally` block, however.)

Comment: This really needs a cat picture: Silently catch ALL the exceptions!

Comment: +1 to all the comments about not doing this for _ALL_ `Throwable` instances. Ignoring some JVM errors, eg `OutOfMemoryError`, can leave the JVM in an inconsistent state leading to subtle bugs that are extremely difficult to diagnose and have the potential to cause silent data corruption (depending on the program).

Comment: @KristianDomagala the reason is not only JVM exceptions, like OOM or something like this, the problem is that there is a set of [exceptions which scala is using for control flow](http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2010/09/20/catching-throwable-in-scala/).

Comment: Do you mean `catch { case NonFatal(t) => }` instead, with the extra `case`?

Comment: How to print `catch { case _: Throwable => }` in this case?

Answer (score 5):

In

```
import scala.util.Try

val res = Try (func()) toOption
```

if the Try is successful you will get a `Some(value)`, if it fails a `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Inside of Scala's catch block you need to use similar construct as in a match statement:

```
try {
  func()
} catch {
  case _: Throwable => // Catching all exceptions and not doing anything with them
}
```

Comment: warning: This catches all Throwables. If this is really intended, use `case _ : Throwable` to clear this warning.
When I add `case _ : Throwable` instead, it won't compile: error: '=>' expected but '}' found

Comment: @tmporaries You need the arrow.  You should write `case _: Throwable =>` to express that you aren't doing it by accident.

Comment: @som-snytt Thanks, you're right. Updated answer with Throwable.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
case x =>
```

in your catch block :)

Comment: This will catch control exceptions as well which is a pretty bad situation, in general.

Answer (score 3):

If annotating with Throwable is burdensome, you can also

```
scala> def quietly[A]: PartialFunction[Throwable, A] = { case _ => null.asInstanceOf[A] }
quietly: [A]=> PartialFunction[Throwable,A]

scala> val x: String = try { ??? } catch quietly
x: String = null
```

which has the small virtue of being self-documenting.

```
scala> val y = try { throw new NullPointerException ; () } catch quietly
y: Unit = ()
```

Edit: syntax changes include fewer braces for try-catch, catching with a function and function literals taken as partial functions:

```
scala> def f(t: Throwable) = ()
def f(t: Throwable): Unit

scala> try throw null catch f
                            ^
       warning: This catches all Throwables. If this is really intended, use `case _ : Throwable` to clear this warning.

scala> def f: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = _ => ()
def f: PartialFunction[Throwable,Unit]

scala> try ??? catch f
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for a sake of completeness, there is a [set of built-in methods in Exception](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$), including silently catching exceptions. See [Using scala.util.control.Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2903481/298389) for details on usage.

Answer (score 2):

I like one of the suggestions here to use `Try()` with `toOption`, but in case you don't want to go further with Option, you can just do:

```
Try(func()) match {
  case Success(answer) => continue(answer)
  case Failure(e) => //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception.catching
catching(classOf[Any]) opt {func()}
```

It generates an Option like in some of the previous answers.