# Code runs with fastOptJS but fails with fullOptJS in Scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I'm catching an UndefinedBehaviorError thrown by the bad asInstanceOf in my code like this:

```scala
$("button").on(
  "click",
  ".showDialog",
  (event: JQueryEventObject) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    val helpText = "Enter any number"
    js.Dynamic.global.swal(
      JC(
        title = helpText,
        text = helpText,
        `type` = "input",
        showCancelButton = true,
        closeOnConfirm = false,
        inputPlaceholder = helpText
      ),
      (input: Any) => {
        try {
          input.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
        } catch {
          case _: Throwable =>
            try {
              val correctInput = input.asInstanceOf[String].toDouble
              global.console.log("success")
            } catch {
              case _: Throwable =>
                js.Dynamic.global.swal.showInputError("Incorrect data!")
            }
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
```

It works fine with fastOptJS but fails with fullOptJS. How to correctly rewrite this code to run it with fullOptJS or what are the other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala.js, a bad cast does not reliably throw a `ClassCastException`, unlike in Scala/JVM. Instead, a bad cast is an *undefined behavior*, as specified [here](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html#undefined-behaviors). This means that in `fullOpt`, the program can behave arbitrarily, and in particular is allowed not in throw. In `fastOpt`, however, the compiler is kind and reliably throws, but *not* a `ClassCastException` (as it would give a false sense of security), rather an `UndefinedBehaviorError`.

`UndefinedBehaviorError`s must never be caught, as catching one *hides a bug* which *will* surface in fullOpt. This is your mistake here: you are catching that `UndefinedBehaviorError` under `case _: Throwable =>`. Note that [catching `Throwable` is bad practice in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21171104/1829647). Instead, you should be using `case scala.util.control.NonFatal(_) =>`. A `NonFatal` handler does *not* catch `UndefinedBehaviorError`, and would therefore not hide the bug.

Now to *solve* your issue, you simply not use `asInstanceOf` as a means to type-test. Even on Scala/JVM, that code would be super bad practice. Use pattern matching instead:

```scala
(input: Any) => {
  def reportIncorrectData(): Unit =
    js.Dynamic.global.swal.showInputError("Incorrect data!")

  input match {
    case input: Boolean =>
      // Here, input is a Boolean
      input
    case input: String =>
      // Here, it is a String; let's try to convert it to Double
      try {
        val correctInput = input.toDouble
      } catch {
        case _: NumberFormatException =>
          reportIncorrectData()
      }
    case _ =>
      // It is something else, always incorrect data
      reportIncorrectData()
  }
}
```