# spark catch all exception and print to to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception

I have some spark code, I need to catch all exception and store to file for some reason, so I tried to catch the exception and print it but its print empty

```
   try {

       /* Some spark code */

       }
   catch {
         case e: Exception => {
          println(" ************** " + e.printStackTrace())
           }
         }
```

output currently printing nothing  ************** ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printStackTrace` doesn't return a stacktrace. It just prints it into the stderr. If you want to store it in the file you can

a) call `e.getStackTrace` and save each element manually

b) call `e.printStackTrace(s)` where `s` is a `PrintStream` or a `PrintWriter` pointing to your output file.

Answer (score -1):

[Please find below the link that has answer to query][1]

[Scala: Silently catch all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170322/scala-silently-catch-all-exceptions)